# Loop through select result with regards to best performance

Tags: postgresql

I have pretty big tables (> 100 million records) and need to write some stored procedures to loop through records and do some additional staff on each iteration. I've read about `for in` and `cursor` approaches. My question is what will be the fastest approach to do it using `cursor`, `for in` or maybe something else with regards to performance?

Comment: loops creates implicit cursor, so there is no difference between them and using cursor explicitly.  If it can be done within one query, than it always be faster, and loop is not needed.

So main question is, what kind of updates will be made to this records.

Answer (score 1):

When using [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) for your stored procedure, you don't have to make that choice, the database will use a cursor anyway:

> (However, PL/pgSQL users do not normally need to worry about that,
> since FOR loops automatically use a cursor internally to avoid memory
> problems.)

Comment: So you mean whatever i pick either '''cursor loop''' or '''FOR temprow IN > LOOP > END LOOP; ''' that will be same performance?

Comment: Yes, that's what the manual tells you and what you can measure on your system. But I always try to avoid loops, many (if not most) problems can be solved without a loop. But without any details about your problem, we can't help you with that.

Comment: Best way always avoid loop it put burden on server >100 million will leads more time to complete

Comment: Simply speaking i want to get records using SELECT inside my sp and then loop through each record and take some column values to do something with them (update another table based on those values)

Comment: That's not really enough detail, but it's very unlikely you need to or should use a loop for what you are describing.

Comment: @Arie: It sounds like you don't need a loop and you could/should handle this as a data set.

Comment: @FrankHeikens May u update your answer and show some example u talking about? Would appreciate + explanation why this instead of loop.

Comment: @FrankHeikens ?

Comment: @Arie: If you have to update table A with results from table B, just join them: UPDATE a SET col1 = b.col3 FROM b WHERE a.id = b.id AND ???;

Answer (score -3):

Best way is not to go with cursor and loop those are always gives slow result.
Better to avoid.
try **Common table expression** it will give fastest Result if there is less CRUD operations.

```
Declare @RowNo int =1;
 ;with ROWCTE as  
   (  
    SELECT @RowNo as ROWNO    
    UNION ALL  
  SELECT  ROWNO+1  
  FROM  ROWCTE  
  WHERE RowNo < 10000
)  
SELECT * FROM ROWCTE  option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: This ain't valid syntax for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Best way always avoid loop it put burden on server >100 million will leads more time to complete

Comment: @FrankHeikens sorry to mention that was Related to MSSQL try to modify accordingly in Postgray

Comment: Cursor behaviour in SQL Server and PostgreSQL is very different. You could use a recursive CTE or generate_series(), but I don't think that would be faster than a loop/cursor. But I would try to avoid all of these constructions, most of the time you don't need them to get your stuff done.

Comment: In the words of Tom Kyte  ( AskTOM) row by row processing is *"slow by slow"* processing. Meaning that **loops are always slow**.  He was speaking of Oracle RDBMS but it applies equally yo Postgres.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Both MSSQL,PGSQL,MYSQL etc all are come under sequel server. Belayer point is correct in any type of DBS

Comment: @UpenderReddy: I fully agree, loops should be avoided like the plague. Don't know why you thought I had a different opinion. All I said was that cursor behaviour in SQL Server and PostgreSQL is different. I also think that a cursor is a useful instrument, but not for looping through results within the database and processing these results within the database: A set-based approach is much easier and faster.